# Get the most recent complete installation DVD of Linux and Ubuntu

Tags: canonical

How do I get the complete installation DVD more recent of Ubuntu and related software?

Looked the site but didn't find how to, also there is little information in Portuguese so I need a professional installation DVD.

Comment: This is the direct url for download of the dvd for 13.04 64bit: [http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a *"Professional"* version of Ubuntu. When you download the ISO image from Ubuntu, you get a fully functional system with some programs by default, that includes:

- Office suite
- Image editor
- Music player
- Video player
- Email client
- Multiprotocol chat client
- whatever you want from the repositories using **Ubuntu Software Center**

You can also select Portuguese before installing the system. When booting from the DVD/CD you can select the Language you want to Install the system from the very start. Just press <kbd>F4</kbd> while booting, then select your preferred language.

If you missed the boot screen, you can select the language after you have hit *Install Ubuntu*:

[image]